# Formatting currency, if no pennies then don't show .00

Tags: javascript

Struggling find the right solution here, using the code below I get the following result:

```
parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-GB')

10000  => 10,000 
512.25 => 512.25
512.20 => 512.2
```

What I would expect is:

```
10000  => 10,000 
512.25 => 512.25
512.20 => 512.20
```

By changing the JavaScript to the below fixes the `512.20` but then I get `10,000.00` which i don't want!

```
parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: "currency", currency: "GBP" })
```

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is just string replace `.00` Edit: Actually, are you doing this with multiple currencies? (So you would have `,00` or `.00`? If so, worth mentioning that in the question)

Comment: How about using `.replace(/\.0+$/, '')` on the result? Using `00` instead of `0+` should work too - as long as there are two minimum fraction digits.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let b = 512.30;
let c = b.toFixed(2).toLocaleString('en-GB')
console.log(c)
```

Comment: `parseFloat('10000').toFixed(2).toLocaleString('en-GB')` = 10000.00, doesn't work

Comment: Read the question again.